# Why does saliva on the finger give correct direction of wind?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, air, evaporation

When we lick a finger and put it up in the air, the side that is cooled is the one facing the direction from which the wind is blowing. But consider this, if we take a cross section of the finger, ie look at it from above, we see the wind blowing at our finger and our finger can be considered to be a cylinder.

From examples like vortex street forming around a cylindrical object, we know that a low pressure exists behind the object. Lower pressure would normally help saliva evaporate faster and thus from this point of view one would expect that the side of the finger away from the wind would evaporate faster.

What is the explanation to this?

Answer (score 3):

First, the reason why the finger becomes more wind-sensitive with some saliva isn't that the saliva evaporates but because the saliva, or water, is a good thermal conductor. The finger has to be warmer than the air so the heat flows from the finger to the air and a good thermal conductor such as saliva helps this flux to take place.

Second, because it's the temperature and not evaporation that matters, we must care about the temperature of the air because this is what is actually cooling the finger. Without any wind, the human body – which is warmer than the air – creates a thin layer of warmed air in the very vicinity of the skin which acts as a thermal insulator and slows down the cooling of the human body.

But the wind disrupts this insulating layer on the front side of the finger and the cooler air gets directly in contact with the finger (or the with saliva on the finger). The air on the opposite side of the finger is either stuck in vortices – that may keep on recycling some warmer air (previously heated by the finger), or if there are no vortices, the air on the opposite side of the finger is still warmer because it was heated up by the finger "recently" when the air was flowing around the finger.

Comment: Regarding your first paragraph, I don't believe that placing a good conductor between two objects will cause a greater heat flux than direct contact between the two objects.  The intervening conductor will introduce some resistance to heat flow that wasn't present otherwise.

Comment: Not evaporation? Doesn't it work in warm air? What's your reference?

Comment: I think the thermal sensitivity disappears in the air of the temperature basically equal to the body temperature. Such a temperature of no sensitivity would exist *even* if the evaporation played a role. There would always be a temperature at which the warming of the finger by the surrounding air would cancel the cooling of the finger by the evaporation. The only question would be what is the temperature - equivalently, what's the ratio of the importance of the cooling by contact and cooling by evaporation. ... I don't have a reference. The very purpose of this page is to become one.

Comment: Above this temperature, the effect gets reversed. If you have a hot air flowing from an oven, the front side of the finger will surely feel warmer.

Comment: @LubošMotl: I have a lot of respect for your good answers, but I think you're mistaken on this one. People whose body temperature is 37C live (and generate body heat) in 40C places where fortunately the humidity is low. They shed the excess calories by evaporation (unless I'm badly mistaken :)

Comment: Mike, I have no doubt that people are cooling themselves by sweating etc. so they can live at temperatures exceeding their body temperature. But that doesn't mean that this evaporative cooling is the main or major reason why the wet finger feels cold. The reason is more similar to the reason why metallic objects feel colder - even though the metal doesn't evaporate - namely the thermal conduction.

Comment: @LubošMotl: Metallic objects will only feel cold if they are below your skin temperature.  However, if you put 40C spit on your finger and put it in 40C wind, the spit will quickly cool to below body temperature and begin cooling your finger.  As an experiment, try wrapping your finger with aluminum foil on a 40C day.  I believe you will get no cooling sensation.

Comment: Dear @James, I think that you are confusing the feeling "this place of skin feels cooler than other pieces of skin" and the feeling "this place of skin is cooler than the body". These are two different things. Both saliva and metals are capable of achieving the former at a place of the skin; while it's hard for both to achieve the latter. Sweating cools the skin as well but the rate of this cooling via evaporation is slower than what one gets due to thermal conduction, or at least you haven't given an argument that would imply otherwise yet.

Comment: @LubošMotl, thanks for the stimulating conversation.  Ok, let's use another thought experiment.  Imagine that your finger is surrounded by a thin layer of sweat starting at skin temperature, then wrapped in thin plastic (like Saran Wrap) so that evaporation is not possible.  I contend that the sweat will not help cool the skin at all.  The only way for the sweat to shed heat in this situation is by convection to the air, but that heat loss could be accomplished just as well without the sweat layer.  If true, this would imply that the ONLY way sweat helps with cooling is via evaporation.

Comment: Or to rephrase what @MikeDunlavey said above, please explain how a conductor placed between a 37C finger and 40C air will cool the finger.

Comment: James, I agree with you - a conductor placed between your body and a 40 degree object will help to *warm* your finger, not to cool it. I am just saying that e.g. at 25 degrees Celsius or similar conditions, the cooling by the contact with the air contributes more to the cooling than cooling by evaporation of any liquid.

Comment: The experiment to try is to go out on a really warm, windy day (over body temperature) and hold two fingers in the air, one wet and one dry.  Which one will feel warmer? I guarantee you that it's the wet one.

Comment: No, my theory predicts that the wet finger will feel colder, too.

Comment: @PeterShor:  Is you comment above a typo? "Which one will feel warmer? I guarantee you that it's the wet one."  It seems to contradict your comment below your answer.  "...evaporation can lower temperatures by several degrees C."

Comment: @James: indeed, it's a typo. Thznks.

Comment: And is Thznks another typo, @PeterShor ?

Answer (score 1):

The percentage by which the pressure lowers on the leeward side of your finger is minuscule, so it barely affects the rate of evaporation.

Comment: But on the upwind side there is a thin boundary layer and air flow over that, carrying away evaporated H2O, much more than on the wind-shadow side, no? (I was in M.E. at MIT. Pp 420 in Rohsenow and Choi, *Heat, Mass, and Momentum Transfer* discusses wet-bulb thermometers. In particular there is a mass-transfer convection term $h_D$. Also pp 384 talks about boundary layers in convection. This doesn't discuss upwind/downwind issues, but I think basic aerodynamics does that.)

Comment: I assume there's higher wind flow, and thus more evaporation, on the upwind side. I don't know enough fluid dynamics to support this, though. The web bulb/dry bulb thermometer method of determining humidity shows that evaporation can lower temperatures by several degrees C.

Comment: But by that logic even if the pressure drop is miniscule, there is increased pressure on the front side; this can cause increased evaporation on the backside.

Comment: Right. There's the increased evaporation from lower pressure on the back side, and there's the increased evaporation from higher wind speed on the front side. One can easily find resources which confirm both of these effects. You might have to search the literature and find numerical values to figure out which effect is larger. (Or you could just determine this experimentally by holding up a wet finger on a windy day.)

Answer (score 0):

I think is somewhat similar to when we blow on our soup to make it cold, or not? The fluid threads lower the pressure on the broth's surface and the water passes from the liquid to the gaseous state more easily due to the lower pressure. Evaporation subtracts energy and cools the soup.

Comment: This is the opposite statement of Lubos Motl's answer. Do you see?

Comment: I do not know really I am so sorry: on science I "play by ear" being a musician (a trumpet player) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a_pePlo3j0I

Comment: In any case, beside my amatorial approach, In effect it seems to be on the opposite side of Lubos Motl's answer's.

Answer (score 0):

What you are feeling is actually an increase in heat flux away from your finger, due to an increase in convective heat transfer from locally impinging flow in the wind direction, along with a major boost in convective heat transfer from the evaporating saliva film.

I'll explain these two phenomena below.

There is impingement flow against your finger coming from the wind. This results in a locally thin boundary layer on the site of impingement, thus increasing convective heat transfer because thinner boundary layers provide less resistance to heat flow.

Furthermore, when you lick your finger, you create a thin evaporating film which increases convective heat transfer even more; a thin layer of evaporating fluid provides a small resistance (it's a thin layer) plus a large latent heat of evaporation required to evaporate. Your skin provides this latent heat.

Comment: Did you read the answer of Lubos Motl? How do you oppose his opinion?

Comment: @jaromrax, my answer is similar to Lubos Motl's, but I think he failed to highlight the main reason the finger loses heat is due a thin saliva film which has a small conduction resistance.

Comment: It is evident there are 2 different opinions. Arguments would make it clear, not statements.